# How to use this UserDao with Date?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-android-extensions, android-date

The app i'm trying to do is based retrieving current day, week and month data from room database, so my entity only contains id and date,
but in an older asked question there was an answer like this:

Date Converter:

```
@TypeConverter
    fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?): Date? {
        return value?.let { Date(it) }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun dateToTimestamp(date: Date?): Long? {
        return date?.time?.toLong()
    }
```

UserDao:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE birthday BETWEEN :from AND :to")
    fun findUsersBornBetweenDates(from: Date, to: Date): List<User>
}
```

When i am using it i don't know in `(from: Date, to: Date)` what to put in Date and retrieve data.
Is there any tutorial or any help online that i missed and might help me?

And please i'm trying to learn and understand how database and date works, so any help counts.

Comment: Do you have a date converter for the user entity?

Comment: @cutiko yes i have and every data successfully enters the database

Comment: can you add your date converter to the question?

Comment: @cutiko I've done it

Comment: `retrieving current day, week and month data from room database` Why do want to retrieve current day from database?

Comment: @ArpitShukla In my app, user tap a button and add data to database, i want to retrieve todays data to give a result to user

Comment: And you have an entity having `Date` field which is saved as a long in the database. Now you want to fetch that data where the stored date represent current date. Right? Btw do you have one entity for each date or can there be multiple entities representing one date?

Comment: @ArpitShukla yes i want to fetch that data where the stored date represents current date, week, month and if i' m understanding correctly your question, yes i have one entity date for each day for example id:1 - Date: 13:58:24 - 16/11/2021, id:2 - Date: 14:32:24 - 16/11/2021 ... id:24 - Date : 03:58:24 - 17/11/2021 (it is an example not actual data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is ROOM doesn't understand `Date` directly that is why you have to use a type converter. Your type converter is Long, so you have Long stored in the DB as `Date`. So what you are doing there is writing: select from this Long equals to Date up to this other Long equal to Date. Room doesn't know what to do.

You have to pass a `Long` in your query and it will work. You can do something like this:

```
@Transaction
fun findUsersBornBetweenDates(from: Date, to: Date): List<User> {
    //convert dates to long
    return findUsersBornBetweenDates(fromLong, toLong)
}

@Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE birthday BETWEEN :from AND :to")
fun findUsersBornBetweenDates(from: Long, to: Long): List<User>
```

The caveat of `@Transaction` is that it doesn't work for `LiveData` so you would have to transform your `Date` to `Long` before reaching the `DAO`.

A very common thing to solve this problem is to re-utilize the `fromTimestamp` and `dateToTimestamp`.

If you really want to see what your DB has stored, I recommend you use the [App Inspection](https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database) tool on Android Studio. Is an integrated DB inspector that allows you to see your tables and perform SQL statements. That way you can see firsthand what is the actual value of the dates in the DB.

Comment: Thank you for your help! For the date to long conversion, the date must be a string?

Comment: Why does the date has to be a String? It is Long in your converter